# Checking to see if any values selected in Slicer

Tags: excel, vba, macos

I have some slicers on a workbook.  For some of the slicers I would like to check to see if anything in that slicer is selected, and, if so, go do some stuff elsewhere in the workbook.
I'm using Excel on Mac.  Below is what I've tried.  It give me an error of "Invalid procedure call or argument" on the "For Each" line.  Any ideas on how to do this?  Where I have MsgBox is where I will be putting my code for doing stuff elsewhere in the workbook.

```
Sub Check_Other_Slicers()
Dim si As SlicerItem

For Each si In ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("District").SlicerItems

    If si.Selected = True Then
        MsgBox "x"
    End If
Next si
End Sub••••ˇˇˇˇ
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following:

```
Sub subCheckSlicerSelection()

    Dim intCnt As Integer
    
    With ThisWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Test")
        
        'Looping through the slicer items
        For intCnt = 1 To .SlicerItems.Count
            
            'Check if the slicer item is selected
            If .SlicerItems(intCnt).Selected Then
                
                'Show the selected value
                MsgBox .SlicerItems(intCnt).Caption
                
            End If
        
        'Next slicer item
        Next intCnt
    
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: I copied and pasted this in to the editor.  I changed "Slicer_Test" to "District" for my slicer and it gives on the "With" line. "Invalid procedure call or argument".  I have verified the name of the slicer.  I've actually checked it with multiple slicers and have gotten the same error.

Comment: OK.  I figured out my issue.  I was using value showed on the workbook when I click on a Slicer.  In Slicer Settings there is a value for "Value to use in formula:".  Here the value was "Slicer_District" and by using this in macro it worked.

Comment: @EricShreve Correct! SlicerCaches are named in that pattern "Slicer_<slicer-name>". Always append the "Slicer_" to your slicer name.